Need to crop the text lines from handwritten image using OpenCV
I have a image which having handwritten texts ...
I need to fetch each lines as images from the image
I used Opencv -> Erode,dilate and morph

kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)

adaptiveImage = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
                             cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 5)
cv2.imshow("Adaptive Threshold", adaptiveImage)
cv2.waitKey()

median = cv2.medianBlur(adaptiveImage,3)
cv2.imshow("median",median)
cv2.waitKey()

# adaptive_morph_open = cv2.morphologyEx(adaptiveImage, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
# cv2.imshow("adaptive_morph_open",adaptive_morph_open)
# cv2.waitKey()


adaptive_morph_close = cv2.morphologyEx(median, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("adaptive_morph_close",adaptive_morph_close)
cv2.waitKey()

# drawBoxes(img,adaptive_morph_close)

kernelHoriontal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, ksize=(5, 1))
adaptiveDilated = cv2.erode(adaptive_morph_close, kernelHoriontal, iterations=12)

I did edges using canny edge but how to make it as complete boundary so that i can crop it and store it as images..pls suggest

